# Embedding Java applets in a Google Sites website

Tags: java, applet, google-sites

I am trying to run some Java code I wrote in a Google Site I have created. I know there's an issue with this but I tried both of the following options:

1. Using the Code Wrapper gadget as described here: http://web.michaelchughes.com/how-to/embed-java-applets-in-google-sites. I used the Code Wrapper gadget from the following URL: http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/105629041657992777031/code-wrapper.xml with the following Javascript code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       /* <![CDATA[ */
           var attributes = {
               code: 'com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class',
               archive: 'http://sites.google.com/site/wimbeep/technology/wimbeeptools.jar',
               width: 500,
               height: 100
           };
             var parameters = { };
             var version = '1.6';
             deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
       /* ]]> */
   </script>
   ```

This does not work - I open a debug console in my Firefox browser and I see that deployJava is undefined.

1. Using the Embed Gadget with  tags:

   <_applet archive="http://sites.google.com/site/wimbeep/technology/wimbeeptools.jar" code="com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class" height="400" width="400"/>

This does not work - I see that the JRE starts but there's an error and the console reports the following:

```
load: class com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class
```

This is really frustrating. I tried many combination, with and without the .class postfix in the code attribute, it just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. That quoted script is what you should use, but that snippet does not import it.  It **is** imported in both the description you linked to, and the [description at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deployingApplets).

Comment: You are right of course and I did use that line importing the variable from www.java.com/fs/deployJava.js and it didn't work. For some reason that line was omitted from the post - edited.

Comment: Sigh  http://sites.google.com/site/mysite/technology/myapplets.jar  when I clicked that link, it is a 404. When I look at that link, it seems to be anonymized.  I don't have time to guess the location of Jars or their content, so here's the deal.  Come up with an actual URL for that Jar & the page that is loading it, and I will offer further help..

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question with the actual site and package names. I really appreciate you trying to help. Thanks.

Comment: @smichak : I guess to host a `JApplet` (if you want an easy way), you doesn't have to pay anyone, if your Service Provider allows you to get Domain Names from someone else. Many sites give free Domain Names, check my [HomePage](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/), you will get those sites. Though now My computer is the Server, so I have to keep it in `ON` state, for others to visit my site :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had encountered a similar problem, and I chose the simple expedient of hosting the applet on another site with an ordinary link posted on [sites.google.com](http://sites.google.com). Alternatively, this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/sites/ask-a-question/rv4t_BOjQuA) suggests loading the applet via [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start), citing this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/fuhrmanator/Home/tft-dice-roller).

Addendum: This (somewhat more transparent) [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) illustrates several approaches.

- Java Web Start
- JWS Applet
- Traditional Applet
- Downloadable JAR with Manifest

Comment: May I ask where are you hosting your applet? Is it a paid web hosting service? Is there a special requirement from such a service?

Comment: @trashgod, Why do you say "expedient"?  Is there something bad about it?

Comment: @trashgod, Google always have this "do it our way" mentality and there are a ton of limitations compared to hosting at Rackspace etc.

Comment: @Pacerier: The downside risk, in this case, is that Time Warner Cable plans to discontinue the service at the end of the month.

Answer (score 2):

I saw it 'load without errors' (then do nothing) locally with this HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WimBeepTools</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet
    code="com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet"
    archive="wimbeeptools.jar"
    width="500"
    height="100">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

That had the HTML and Jar in the same directory, so load that HTML up at http://sites.google.com/site/wimbeep/technology/applet001.html & the applet should load successfully.

Be sure to add the `001` suffix to ensure we can check other variants in case of initial failure.  The page seen by users should be at another URL.

### BTW

#### Use code formatting for HTML

> <_applet archive="http://sites.google.com/site/wimbeep/technology/wimbeeptools.jar" code="com.fusego.wimbeep.applet.ScreamURLApplet.class" height="400" width="400"/>

Was the initial `_` to prevent the site 'swallowing' the HTML?  Put HTML (JNLP/XML/Input/Output ***&*** source code) in code tags.  The applet element was never intended to be 'self-closed' with a `/>`.  Add the closing applet element as in my example.

#### Sort the details first

Ultimately it is best to use the `deployJava.js` to write the element that embeds the applet when deploying.  But first, fix the paths and other attribute details using 'plain old HTML' & the `applet` element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have uploaded your HTML code to http://sites.google.com/site/wimbeep/technology/applet001.html but I'm still getting a ClassNotFoundException for ScreamURLApplet.

Comment: When I click that link I see *"Sites
Download Attachment

Click here to download your attachment."*  When I 'click here' it downloads the file to a temp directory before showing it in FF.  Obviously it is not going to work that way.  Can't you make the page available in the normal way?

Comment: It's a Google Sites website. I can only add attachments to pages which are downloaded as general purpose files by browsers. I can add HTML code to a page in an HTML box or in a Code Wrapper gadget and I tried it but it doesn't work for the same reason (ClassNotFoundException).

Comment: *"I can add HTML code to a page in an HTML box or in a Code Wrapper gadget"* So ***do*** that so.. *"and I tried"* ***..I*** can try it, and investigate other things besides.

Comment: @trashgod  Well blow me down.  I had been thinking this entire thread, thoughts to the effect..  "Well I know *you* can do it, so it must be possible".  Seems I was leading the OP astray!  Thanks for chiming in, I'm almost ready to abandon further attempts on the grounds they are 'pointless'.

Comment: @trashgod It's still a bit kludgy in not being able to use JS to check JRE etc. but that is what I **should** have suggested as an answer 2 days ago!  Can you upgrade it to an answer so I can up-vote?  It is a pity that there are so many barriers to successful applet/rich client deployment from Google sites. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Not as seamless as an embedded applet, but I can see the value. I've elaborated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10364345/230513). Critical review always welcome.