# How to save code for Java applets

Tags: java, applet, google-sites

I am thoroughly confused as to what part of my code I need to put onto a website in order for me to embed this as a gadget in Google Sites. One source that I found said that I should have both my main class as one file and my whole project as another. I am using Google Code, and have gotten my main class (which is saved as a .java file), and the rest of my project (which is saved as a .jar file) onto the code file cabinet.

Currently, I am getting an error with my code not being able to find the class that contains my main(String[] args) {} method. Officially, it is a ClassNotFoundException, with the text Main.java, which is the name of my 'code' in HTML. If you want to see it for a reference, here is the HTML that I am using for my Google site:

```
<applet name="UnderLD" code="Main.java" archive="UnderLudumDare.jar"
    codebase="http://wierd0games.googlecode.com/svn/"
     width = 300 height = 168>
Sorry, this Applet could not be started. Please make sure that Java 1.4.2 (or later) is installed and active in your browser (<a href="http://java.sun.com/getjava">Click here to install Java now</a>)
</applet>
```

However when I paste the link for the codebase in my brower, the java.Main class (the one with my main method) is the first on the list. To me, I am doing everything correctly according to all of the tutorials I have found, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling the main class into the jarfile?

Comment: Yes, a non-Runnable one.

Answer (score 0):

code should be the name of *class file* for the applet, not the name of the *source file*. The trailing `.class` is optional but Sun now recommends omitting it. All of the main browsers will work with or without the `.class` suffix.

So both of the following should work, provided `Main.class` is in the root of the jar file:

```
code="Main.class"

code="Main"
```

---

Source [Using applet, object and embed Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html#applet)

> `code = appletFile`
>
> This required attribute gives the name of the file that contains the
>   applet's compiled Applet subclass. This file is relative to the base
>   URL of the applet. It cannot be absolute. One of code or object must
>   be present. The value appletFile can be of the form classname.class or
>   of the form packagename.classname.class.

Comment: I changed the code attribute to both Main.class and Main, and still got the same error message about it not being able to find my class. Could it perhaps be my codebase that is incorrect?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

If the class and/or jar files are in the same directory on the web server as the html invoking the applet then you don't need a codebase

Comment: The title of the error message is ClassNotFoundException. In the box where there is usually text, all it says is the word 'Main', for when I put Main instead of Main.java in the HTML, and 'Main.class' for when I put main.class as the code attribute. My class and JAR file is on a code.google site, while my website is in a google.site server. So they are different directories and I need a codebase, correct? Also, if you would like to see the error yourself, here is the link to my site:https://sites.google.com/site/wierd0games/under-ludum-dare

Comment: Ok. See this answer for applets on google sites ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306127/embedding-java-applets-in-a-google-sites-website?rq=1